# Arreglo de Fechas JQuery

Tags: jquery, date

Alguien que me pueda ayudar a realizar un arreglo de de fechas, con JQuery.

Quiero realizar un arreglo de fechas "6 aproximadamente o mas", a partir de una fecha dada, la fecha sera asignada por el usuario en un input, una vez que el usuario selecciona la fecha:   `var fech = $("#fecha").val();`
, por ejemplo '2017/11/22' crear un arreglo

```
fechas = [{'2017/11/23},{'2017/11/24},{'2017/11/25},{'2017/11/27},{'2017/11/28},{'2017/11/29}];
```

ademas de omitir las fechas del día domingo.
Alguien que me pueda ayudar con ello¿? no tengo la menor idea de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira este ejemplo.

En el evento `change` del `input` se captura la fecha a partir del valor y se añade un día.

A partir de ahí entra en un bucle en el que se va añadiendo un día después de cada ciclo y que finaliza cuando el array `fechas` tiene 6 elementos.

Dentro del bucle se comprueba si el día calculado es domingo y, si no lo es, se añade al array.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#fecha').change(function(){
    var date = new Date($(this).val());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    if (date){
      var fechas = [];
      for (;fechas.length < 6; date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)){
        if (date.getDay() > 0)
          fechas.push(date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate());
      }
      console.log(fechas);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="fecha">
```

Comment: Me funciona perfecta, pero... si la fecha solo quiero que aparezca '2017-11-23' solo eso sin los demás dato.. ''T00:00:00.000Z"  o un mi caso "
Wed Nov 22 2017 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)"

Comment: No tienes más que crear el string con el formato que desees a partir de la fecha. He modificado el ejemplo para meter el dato en el array como un string con el formato que buscas.

Comment: Gracias amigo me funciono al 100